# Are test/bump functions always bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

A bump function is a infinitely often differentiable function with compact support. I guess that such functions are always bounded, especially because the set where they are not zero is compact and because they are continuous they should attain a maximum value on that set. or am I wrong? I am wondering because nowhere in the literature I am using there it is said that such functions are bounded, and I guess this is an important property and think it should be mentioned if it holds. So maybe it's not the case?

Comment: They are bounded. So are their derivatives. It's one of things that are considered too obvious to mention.

Comment: You should check out the extreme value theorem.

Comment: This is an important property, but it's understood that continuous functions with compact support are bounded.

Comment: A very late comment: A function with "compact support" does not mean "the set where they are not zero is compact." It just means there is a compact set in the domain such that the function is zero outside that conpact set. Indeed. $U=f^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$ is open if $f$ is continuous. So if the domain is connected, $U$ is closed only when $U=\emptyset$ or the whole domain, hence rarely compact. So "compact support" is equivalent to  $\overline U,$ the closure of $U,$ being compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: The image of a compact set under a continuous function is always compact.