# Continuous superposition of bump functions

Tags: functions, special-functions, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to "model" Fig 2 with a superposition of a [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). I understand that [bump functions are bounded and can be often differentiated](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160485/23593). The bump function I have used is shown in **Fig 1**.

**My bump function:**

$$f(x)=exp\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2-L^2}\right)$$

$L$ varies from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and produces the plot below (FIG 1):

[image: FIG 1: Bump function]

**FIG 2What I am trying to model through a superposition of such bump functions [ALSO AVAILABLE HERE](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/IMAG0303.jpg):**

[image: FIG2: I would like to model this with a continuous bump function]

***What kind of superposition*** of bump functions will I need? I have tried fractional additive superpositions such as:

$$f(x)=exp\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2-L^2}\right) +0.01 exp\left(\frac{(x+2)^2}{x^2-L^2}\right)$$

$\ldots$ but that didn't work!

**EDIT 1: Per fgp's comment below**:

$L$ is a constant. In my plot $x$ ranges between $-L$ to $L$. I used Mathematica to do this plot and the code, in case anyone is interested is:

```
L=\[Pi];
f= Exp[x^2/(x^2-L^2)]
Plot[
f,
{x,-L,L}
]
```

**EDIT 2: In an attempt to "scale and translate" as per Henning Malkholm, I produced this monstrosity which is not quite correct**

$$a \exp \left(\frac{(2 x+3 \pi )^2}{(2 x+3 \pi )^2-(3 \pi )^2}\right)+a \exp \left(\frac{(2 x-3 \pi )^2}{(2 x-3 \pi )^2-(3 \pi )^2}\right)+\exp \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2-L^2}\right)$$

[image]

The scale factor `a` did not make too much of a difference as a number. I suppose I would need a function `a=a(x)` to do this.

Any ideas at this stage would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what you *independent* variable is supposed to be. You define the bump function as $f(x) = \ldots$, but then say "L varies... " when describing the plot. Which is it?

Comment: @fgp apologies. On a semi regular basis, the engineer in me murderizes the mathematician. The `x` varies from 0 to L. I hope that provides clarity?

Comment: That murderous engineer has killed again, I fear... I think you mean $x$ varies from $-L$ to $L$...

Comment: @fgp yes. Thank you for catching that. Working on translation as suggested by Henning Makholm below.

Answer (score 4):

How about just scaling and translating?

$$ g(x) = f(x) + af(2x-3\pi) + af(2x+3\pi)$$
where $f$ is your original bump function, for some appropriate coefficient $a$.

If that "doesn't work", you'll need to define "works" more clearly and tell us *how* it doesn't work.

---

**Edit after question was updated:** I see what's happening. Your bump function should actually be

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2-L^2} \right) & \text{when } |x|<L \\
0 & \text{when } |x|\ge L\end{cases} $$

Outside the interval $(-L,L)$ the first expression will give you large numbers that are *not* part of the bump, so you need a piecewise definition to get rid of them.

Comment: @HenningMalkholm That was a good idea and I tried it. It would seem that the coefficient `a` would need to be a "curvature" type term? Right now I have discontinuities in my plot. See updated question. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @drN: No, $a$ is just a constant -- but you need to explicitly suppress the part of the bump function that is outside the support.

Comment: @HenningMakhold Yes I thought about a piecewise function but decided against it in case in is not "discretized" correctly with finite difference schemes and such. The pcw/s function, however, needs to be three part and I tried that (will include code soon) with no success!

Comment: @drN: Bump functions _do_ need to be piecewise defined -- there's no getting around it.

Comment: I forgot to add that with the pcw/s function you have recommended, I will have only one "bump". I am looking at getting a central bump and "satellite" bumps of smaller amplitude around it. I believe these are called compactons.

Comment: @drN: The piecewise $f$ I show in the second part of the answer is supposed to be the one that plugs into the expression for $g$ in the first equation.